# hangindent hangafter document-wise settings

Tags: indentation

I'm after paragraphs where lines after the 1st are indented (the 1st line isn't), e.g.
Text ...
this is the 2nd line
this is the 3rd line

Setting \hangindent & \hangafter in the preamble doesn't set them document-wise,  only to the paragraph which follows. MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\hangindent=2cm
\hangafter=1
\parindent=0cm
\begin{document}
\blindtext

\blindtext
\end{document}
```

The 2nd blindtext doesn't have the needed  indentations.

However, this works:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\hangindent=2cm
\hangafter=1
\parindent=0cm
\begin{document}
\blindtext

\hangindent=2cm
\hangafter=1
\parindent=0cm
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

Is there a way to set \hangindent & \hangafter globally w/o repeating them per paragraph?.

Thanks

Comment: Does your document contain just standard paragraphs or also section titles or lists? The main problem is that `\hangindent` and `\hangafter` are reset at every `\par` command (that might be generated via macros or by a blank line). Maybe you want negative parindent, instead.

Comment: Thanks . I've tried it both with sections and without. The outcome is identical - the \hangafter & \hangindent had to be copied before every paragraph the indentation was needed. Setting them in the preamble didn't set them "globally".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You asked,

> Is there a way to set `\hangindent` & `\hangafter` globally w/o repeating them per paragraph?

Yes: Just load the [hanging](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/hanging) package, issue the instruction `\begin{hangparas}{2cm}{1}` where you want hanging indentation to begin (this could be immediately after `\begin{document}`), and issue the instruction `\end{hangparas}` where you want hanging indentation to end (this could be immediately before `\end{document}`).

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try. As I've replied above setting the commands in the preamble didn't  apply them document-wise, which is contrary to https://bityl.co/BrPO .

Comment: @jzz11 - Not sure what you're refering to when you say that you apply the commands `\begin{hangparas}{2cm}{1}` and `\end{hangparas}` in the preamble. To me, these two instructions can occur only in the body of the document, and certainlly not in the preamble.

Comment: @jzz11 So have you tried Mico's answer. If not, why not! It works unless you have done something you haven't told us about. --- GOM

Comment: Thanks. Worked perfectly. Cheers